# How to build ARMA or ARIMA models?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, statsmodels, arima

I am trying to use Statsmodel in python to view the predicted and residual error plots, however, when I use the orders (which can be found in photos and code). However, when I run the code I keep on getting the following error for the MA model for both ARMA and ARIMA model.

```
ValueError: The computed initial MA coefficients are not invertible. You should induce invertibility, choose a different model order, or you can pass your own start_params.
```

How can I fix the problem?

Additional questions:

- How would I be able to Implement ARX Model in python?
- Did I select the right order for the models or used the right plots to obtain the orders?
- Is it possible to create the models separately? like use the AR model first and then the MA model?
- How is it possible to use this as a feature extraction in machine learning?

Code: (process_y variable is processed signal after signal processing stage)

```
result = adfuller(process_y)
print('ADF Statistic: %f' % result[0])
print('p-value: %f' % result[1])
print('Critical Values:')
for key, value in result[4].items():
    print('\t%s: %.3f' % (key, value))

if result[0] < result[4]["5%"]:
    print("Reject Ho - FRAN Time Series is Stationary")

    # fit model
    order = (1, 2)

    model = ARMA(process_y, order=order)  # Using Norm only
    # model = ARIMA(process_y, order=(1, 0, 2))  # Using Processed only

    model_fitted = model.fit()
    print('The lag value chose is: %s' % model_fitted.k_ar)
    print('The coefficients of the model are:\n %s' % model_fitted.params)

    # make prediction:
    predictions = model_fitted.predict()

    # errors:
    residuals = []
    # for i in range(len(process_y)):
    # for i in range(4962):
    for i in range(len(process_y) - model_fitted.k_ar):
        residuals.append(process_y[i] - predictions[i])
    # print('Residuals: ', residuals)

else:
    print("Failed to Reject Ho - FRAN Time Series is Non-Stationary")
```

**ACF and PACF Plots**

[ACF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxwWS.png)
[PACF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br7PX.png)

**Orders Plot**

[MA Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtB4L.png)
[AR Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZTZg.png)

**Entire error message**

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyCharm Projects\Time-Domain response\test TSA ver. 9.py", line 899, in <module>
    model_fitted = model.fit()
  File "PyCharm Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py", line 985, in fit
    start_params = self._fit_start_params((k_ar, k_ma, k), method,
  File "PyCharm Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py", line 577, in _fit_start_params
    start_params = self._fit_start_params_hr(order, start_ar_lags)
  File "PyCharm Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py", line 562, in _fit_start_params_hr
    raise ValueError("The computed initial MA coefficients are not "
  ValueError: The computed initial MA coefficients are not invertible. You should induce invertibility, choose a different model order, or you can pass your own start_params.
```

Comment: **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].**

Comment: @AMC the error is in the question, Value Error

Comment: The **entire** error message, that's all the output?

Comment: @AMC See the edited question

Comment: @Momo Can you provide a **_minimal_** reproducible example please? I.e. strip all the stuff that isn't required to reproduce the problem. That also means including some sample data which can be used to fit the model.

Comment: @a_guest How about now?